# Python coding help for a newbie

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to coding and I'm trying to figure a simple code. The user will input a number, that must be an integer greater than 0, then asked to enter a second integer, greater than the previous one. once the second value is entered the two inputs should be displayed as well as the even and odd numbers in-between the two inputs. Currently, the code I have doesn't distinguish the value of the second input, allowing it to be lesser than the previous one.

```
number = input('please enter a number:')
val = int(number)

if val > 0:
    integer = raw_input('please pick a second integer:')
    if raw_input < val:
        print 'please pick an integer greater than the previos input'
    if raw_input > val:
        print

if val < 0:
    print 'please pick a positive integer greater than zero'
```

Comment: You'll have to put each input in a `while` loop and keep prompting the user until they give a valid input.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you added your code as an image. Please post it directly in the answer. The page [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might be a good read. Additionally, I don't see how this question relates to Vim, so you may want to remove that tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could ask for the inputs before the while loop check and then ask again, but I like the cleaner appearance of only having the input prompt appear once in the code, so we can set up some conditions that will trigger the loop and the prompt.

We can initialize `num1 = -1` and then our `while` loop condition will be triggered and repeat until we receive and `int` larger is larger than `0`.

Then we can do the same with `num2` by initializing it as `num1 - 1`, this will trigger our `while` loop that will continue to prompt until `num2` is greater than `num1`.

Finally we can `print` a `list` of the `range` from `num1` to `num2 + 1` since the end is not inclusive we should extend the range by `1`

```
num1 = -1
while num1 <= 0:
    num1 = int(input('Enter a number greater than 0: '))

num2 = num1 - 1
while num2 <= num1:
    num2 = int(input('Enter a number greater than {}: '.format(num1)))

print(list(range(num1, num2+1)))
```

> ```
> Enter a number greater than 0: 1
> Enter a number greater than 1: 5
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> ```